# Can't install Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 7 using a usb pen drive

Tags: windows, usb

I downloaded the desktop version of Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit and installed it in my computer with the "Universal Usb Installer". I restarted the computer and the computer automaticaly ran the Ubuntu Instalation. I set it to install alongside Windows 7. I was planning to leave 80GB for Windows and 170GB for Ubuntu. After I set everything, I cliked to install and then came my problem. It wouldn't install. It was taking an awful lot of time so I saw there was an error message (I don't know what exactly) appearing on the instalation screen. I had to abruptly stop the whole operation because there wasn't a button to cancel! 
My Windows seems to be fine and I'm not having any problems with it. And you probably should know that there are no more than 10GBs of files and software on my computer.

P.S.: Sorry, if it was hard to understand. I don't really know much about computer and I'm new to Ubuntu and obviously English isn't my first language!

Comment: Please supply the error message, else it is pretty much a shot in the dark trying to help you. Was the message before or after the Ubuntu CD started?

Answer (score 1):

You should have probably let the install finish. The error could be totally normal. As is ERROR can't do thing one so doing thing 2.

There is not a cancel button because it is not safe to cancel at the point you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you install ubuntu, choose something else. and delete unused space for swap area, and ubuntu system. Make sure the format is '/'. i think that's the center of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from
   CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a
   LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
2. Install and run Boot-Repair
3. Click "Recommended Repair".

Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

[More info and options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

I know you said that you installed Windows 8, then Ubuntu, but it seems like GRUB didn't get installed somehow.